# How to get a response from Curl using Java or Apache wicke 6.x

Tags: java, apache, curl, wicket

I am a newbie with an issue that has been storming my head for quite sometime..

How can I use Java or Apache Wicket 6.x to connect to this URL and get the response as shown below

```
POST URL: https://checkout.simplepay.ng/v2/payments/card/charge/

curl "https://checkout.simplepay.ng/v2/payments/card/charge/" \
     -d token= 'tk_iKdhkLxPZEaGoNodfWoEFW' \
     -d amount= '110000' \
     -d amount_currency= 'NGN' \
     -u test_pr_demo: ‘test_pr_demo’'

RESPONSE FORMAT

{
    u'customer': 
        {
            u'address_city': u'', 
            u'address_postal': u'110001', 
            u'address': u'17 Da Silva St, Lekki, Lagos, Nigeria',
             u'email': u'joshua@simplepay.ng', 
             u'phone': u'+2347035706380', 
             u'address_state': None, 
             u'address_country': u'NG', 
             u'id': u'cus_CKX7mSkCFgkyiz4oHDY2mW'
         }, 
     u'created': 1494677790, 
     u'response_code': 20000, 
     u'livemode': False, 
     u'currency': u'NGN', 
     u'source': 
         {
             u'exp_month': 12, 
             u'funding': u'credit', 
             u'brand': u'VISA', 
             u'object': u'card', 
             u'last4': u'1111', 
             u'exp_year': 2018, 
             u'id': u'card_2aP8nZNtHDp9dkNPrbKsYc', 
             u'is_recurrent': False
         }, 
     u'amount': 6000000, (amount in cents)
     u'payment_reference': u'1850877790146606', 
     u'id': u'trans_67UQe4iSZQr6NdXjgBT57R', 
     u'captured': True
 }

'response_code': 20000,  Signifies a verified payment
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a Java HTTP client library.

There are more sophisticated ones like:

- https://hc.apache.org/
- https://square.github.io/okhttp/

And simple ones like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

With any of them you can make GET/POST/PUT/... requests and then process the response however you need.